# Google Drive Backup and Sync will not download to PC

Tags: google-drive, google-backup-and-sync

I have 22GB of data in Google Drive, and have installed the "Backup and Sync" client from [here](https://www.google.com/drive/download/). I've set this up to download from Google Drive to a local folder, and launched the client. It creates an icon in the system tray. When I open that icon, it begins a sync by counting 29115 files, then stopping, saying "Updated". But the local folder is still empty.

- Cleared Chrome cache, history, cookies, everything, all time (even though not using Chrome as the client, perhaps Backup and Sync is.
- Logged out of my account in Chrome
- Restarted the computer
  After these steps, the behavior of backup and sync is the same every time. Counts files to download, doesn't actually download. I've tried waiting hours with it running, and nothing is downloaded.
  There are apparently no log files either, at least in the location of the client, "C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe"

Comment: Try the steps [listed here](https://www.guidingtech.com/google-drive-wont-sync-windows-10/).

Comment: yeh already did, that wasn't helpful.